# Run Get-PnpListItem on subfolders

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to get some info on files with lots of versions in SharePoint online and using Get-PnPListItem  for it. The issue is - it times out when going through the site with lots of files. So I want to run this command on each subfolder rather then on whole Shared Document folder and I created following script:

```
function rKGetFileVersions { 
  param ([string]$folderf );  
   Write-Host "-- **** F: " $folderf " ********* "  
   $FFItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $folderf -Query $Fquery  -Connection $con 
    ForEach($fItem in $FFItems){ 
        if($fItem.FileSystemObjectType -like "*File*"){ 
           Write-Host "File: " $folderf "/" $fItem["FileLeafRef"] 
           $Vs = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $fItem -Property Versions -Connection $con 
            if($Vs.Count -gt 400){  # more than 400 versions so capture file info into  
               write-host -f Cyan "Versions: " $Vs.count " - " $Item["FileRef"] 
            } 
        }elseif ($fItem.FileSystemObjectType -like "*Folder*") {   
            Write-Host "Folder: " $folderf "/" $fItem["FileLeafRef"] $fItem["GUID"] 
            rKGetFileVersions($folderf+"/"+$fItem["FileLeafRef"]);      
        }else { 
            Write-Host "   == NONE== " $fItem.ServerRelativeUrl  
        } 
    } 
} 

#------- Global SP App ------------ 

$Mfolder =  "Shared Documents" 

$Fquery = "<View Scope='Default'><FieldRef Name=''/></View>" 

rKGetFileVersions($Mfolder);
```

But I am getting error "List doesnt exist" when its trying to go to subfolders. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use Get-PnPFolderItem instead to achieve this.

For example:

```
Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl "Shared Documents/subfolder"
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if I can use "Get-PnPProperty -Property Versions" with "Get-PnPFolderItem". I tried  Get-PnPFileVersion, but it seams to be downloading all file versions, unlike "Get-PnPProperty -Property Versions"